# Is it possible to replace, or modify Windows Active Directory authentication mechanism

Tags: windows, authentication, active-directory

We have an authentication product, and we would like to integrate it directly into Windows Active Directory, to either replace, or enhance the standard username/password authentication mechanism. Is there any 'approved' way you can replace or modify the AD authentication?

e.g. is there an API that you can integrate with, to install your own authentication plugins into the auth stack or anything similar?

Comment: The standard login method for Active Directory (or Windows authentication, really) is Kerberos. Are you looking to replace that (probably not likely possible) or put another authentication layer on top of that?

Comment: Either really. We are just looking for options.